# How to create button dynamically from one activity to another activity

Tags: android, button, dynamically-generated

I am creating an android application that consists of adding button dynamically.Here when I click the button in one activity then a button will dynamically created another activity. Is it possible to create a button when clicking a button in one activity then create a button in another activity.Please help me with this.

```
package com.example.dynamicbutton;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button Add_Button;
    Activity_2 act_child;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Add_Button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_add);
        Add_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent invisible = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity_2.class);
                startActivity(invisible);
                act_child.visible.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: I tried by setting button visibility Visible.GONE and View.VISIBLE from parent activity.

Comment: You need to click a button and create one button in next activity. else no button is that what you want ?

Comment: I didn't understand your logic ! !  Whats your requirment ? Could you please more clear ? ?

Comment: Yup when i click a button in one activity create one button in next activity otherwise no button in that activity @Amsheer

Comment: when i click a button in one activity create one button in next activity otherwise no button in that activity @DonChakkappan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple.Do Following in First Activity.
If the button clicked use following.

```
Intent invisible = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity_2.class);
//here add this line
.putExtra("visibility", "1");
                startActivity(invisible);
```

else

```
Intent invisible = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity_2.class);
    //here add this line
    .putExtra("visibility", "0");
                    startActivity(invisible);
```

In your Second Activity:

```
String visibility = getIntent().getStringExtra("visibility");
if (visibility.equals("1")){
 act_child.visible.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else{
 act_child.visible.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't make variables public.Change your design to

1 ] Pass some variable to Second Activity . (In Button click of First Activity).

2 ] Get the variable in Second Activty & change the visibilty of Button (in Second Activity according to that variable)

```
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("flag","show");
startActivity(i);


Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("flag");
    if(value.equals("show")){
button1.setVisible(View.Visible);  
}
else{
button1.setVisible(View.Gone);
}
```